# Android addPreferencesFromResource

Tags: android, android-preferences

I decided to learn android and I bought a book Hello, Android Introducing Google's Mobile Development Platform, Third Edition. I started to do my first project Sudoku from the book and I have managed to do it until when I need it create class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity. The method addPreferencesFromResource(R.XML.Settings) do not work any more with PreferenceActivity. I am trying to fix this problem for two day without success for.
What I have so far! I read that I could manage it via PerformanceFragment and I try to follow this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html and I did following:

```
public class Prefs extends PreferenceFragment {
     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
       }
}
```

It appears an error and Eclipse recommend to add @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
when I did it, I could compile it and run my emulator but when I press menu and settings I have received message Unfortunately, Sudoku has stopped.

Other codes in mainActivity I have:

```
package org.example.sudoku;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class MainActivitySudoku extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_sudoku);

        //setting up click listener for all buttons

        View continueButton = findViewById(R.id.continu_button);
        continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        View newButton = findViewById(R.id.new_button);
        newButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        View aboutButton = findViewById(R.id.about_button);
        aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        View exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
        exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    // other codes...   

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.settings:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Prefs.class));
            return true;
        }
        return  false;
    }
```

inside Sudoku/res/xml/settings.xml I have xml codes:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="music"
            android:title="@string/music_title"
            android:summary="@string/music_summary"
            android:defaultValue="true" />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="hints"
            android:title="@string/hints_title"
            android:summary="@string/hints_sammary"
            android:defaultValue="true" />      

    </PreferenceScreen>

    Last thing to mention is AndroidManifest Sudoku/bin/AndroidManifest.xml I have following codes:

    $ <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="org.example.sudoku"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >
        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="10"
            android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivitySudoku"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".About"
                android:label="@string/about_title"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".Prefs"
                android:label="@string/settings_title"
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Well, could anyone please help me how to fix this problem. I have looked at on some examples but I could not figure it out. Also if anybody knows a book that would be better to follow exercises it would be great! Thank you David

Answer (score 0):

> The method addPreferencesFromResource(R.XML.Settings) do not work any more with PreferenceActivity

It should. It is deprecated, but it should still work.

> I have received message Unfortunately, Sudoku has stopped

I'm pretty sure that Ed covers [LogCat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this) in his book, which is how you learn more about problems like this.

In this case, you are probably getting a `ClassCastException`. Your `Intent` for `startActivity()` is:

```
new Intent(this, Prefs.class)
```

However, `Prefs` is a `PreferenceFragment`, not an `Activity`. You need to have your `<activity>` element point to an `Activity`, presumably a `PreferenceActivity`, one that uses your `PreferenceFragment`.

> Also if anybody knows a book that would be better to follow exercises it would be great!

Asking for off-site resources is considered off-topic for Stack Overflow. That being said, I recommend you pick a book that was published this year. The book that you are using was published four years ago, and that is a *long* time in Android development.